# Not able to add Custom-App in frappe docker

Tags: docker, containers, erpnext, frappe, custom-application

Following this URL https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker/blob/main/docs/custom-apps.md

But unable to add Custom App as cannot add custom app through APPS_JSON

I tried this URL https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker/blob/main/docs/custom-apps.md

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you still connect to this bench console on the dockerized version? If so, this is how it could possibly be done.

Start the server, or make sure the server is running

```bash
bench start
```

Using another instance of the terminal, navigate to the bench directory

Make sure your bench instance is in developer mode

```bash
bench set-config -g developer_mode 1
```

Clear default site cache

```bash
bench --site yoursite.local clear-cache
```

Create new Frappe App (in this case you've already done this)

```bash
bench new-app app_name_here
```

Installing Frappe App

```bash
bench --site yoursite.local install-app app_name_here
```

The migrate command updates the site's state to the current available apps.

```bash
bench migrate
```

Comment: Is this even possible without making the whole image for docker? Shouldn't the apps folder be in a writable/expanding docker volume? It would be nice if it can be done that way. You could use vanilla image and add all the apps you want to it.